# How are districts defined and scored in Ticket to Ride: London?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, ticket-to-ride-london

I have two closely related questions about "districts" in Ticket to Ride: London.

1. How are districts defined?
2. How many points do you get for completing a district?

Comment: This is literally a question of "I can't be bothered reading the rulebook" and has no place kn a general reference Q&A site. If you have actual doubt about the meaning of a particular or definition, perhaps difficulty or ambiguity in identifying a district and its score, ask that. Otherwise this is not worth the server space to keep.

Comment: (Added [tag:ticket-to-ride]. The usual practice is to tag the base game, even if it doesn't directly relate to it.)

Answer (score 2):

"What are districts in the game Ticket to Ride: London?"

Quoting from the [official rules](https://cdn.svc.asmodee.net/production-daysofwonder/uploads/2023/09/720061-T2RLN-Rules-EN.pdf):

> A District is made up of Locations of the same colour and number.

For example (and in fact the example used in the rules), Buckingham Palace, Big Ben, Tralfalgar Square and Piccadilly Circus make up a district as they are the four locations on the board marked with a green "2".

"How do we get to know about the points we gain from a district?"

The very next sentence in the rules is

> This number is also the Points value of the District.

e.g. you score 2 points for the Buckingham Palace/Big Ben/Tralfalgar Square /Piccadilly Circus district, because it is marked with a "2". Covent Garden and the British Museum would score you only 1 point, because it is marked with a "1".